# How to create variables with dynamic [incremental] names in Scala

Tags: scala, variables, dictionary

I want to create a set of variables with dynamic names and assigning each of them in for loop, for example:

```
val V1,V2,V3,V4

for (i<- 1 until 5){
   V<i>=doc1.map(array of string)
}
```

How can i create these variables?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an array?

Comment: how can i use an array?

Comment: Scala is not an interpreted language. There is no real way of assigning a value to a "dynamic" variable, i.e. a variable with a name only known at runtime. However, I suspect there is an easier (and more comprehensible) solution to your problem. Could you provide some more context?

Comment: You could use reflection, but I would not recommend that. Why not use a collection? By the way `V1, V2, V3, V4` would need to be `var` for anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an array in Scala just like in any other programming language. The syntax varies slightly from Java

```
val v = new Array[String](5)
for (i <- 1 until 5)
  v(i) = doc1.map(array of string)
```

Notes: The variable needs to start with a lower case letter. Array indexes in Scala start at zero, so you have to be careful about the number of items you allocate for your array (5) versus the last index of the array (4). Unlike Java, your array index `v(i)` is enclosed in round braces instead of square braces.

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Array for more details.

Comment: thanks @Bob , this code shows : (Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Array[String])

Comment: @AHAD if your variables are of type `Array[String]`, then change `v` to `Array[Array[String]]`.